# Find the right actuator to control the flow of flour

Tags: actuator

I'm building a circuit to control the flow of flour. The basic idea is to open that actuator (Possibly valve?) to let a specific amount go through and then close it. The tube should have a diameter of 1cm max.

I wonder what is the right actuator to use? Maybe a valve is the right one? Any other solution? Also, it would be great if you pointed out some suitable actuators that I can buy online.

Comment: Also see  [What would be the best way to handle food grains?](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1145/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-handle-food-grains)